# Salesforce SFDX getting error while creating project

Tags: salesforce, command-line-interface

I have latest Salesforce CLI version and while creating new project I am getting below error.

Starting SFDX: Create Project
09:17:56.406 sfdx force:project:create --projectname HelloWorld --outputdir d:\lightning Web Componant --template standard
ERROR running force:project:create:  Command failed with exit code 1: npm root -g --prefix d:\lightning Web Componant.yo-repository --loglevel error
'npm' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
09:18:07.277 sfdx force:project:create --projectname HelloWorld --outputdir d:\lightning Web Componant --template standard
 ended with exit code 1

Answer (score 1):

I have installed node.js from this link https://nodejs.org/en/download/ and also installed "Node.js Extension Pack " to fix the issue.

Answer (score -1):

Installing node.js fixed the error for me.